# Positive Edge Triggered D-FF by switches

Tags: digital-logic, switches, flipflop, rom

if Given that this circuit implements Positive Edge Triggered D-FF so **What is the purpose of the switches S2 and S4**? Hwo can i know what is the kind of S2 and what is the kind of S4 (P or N)?
[image: the circle]

Comment: Homework? Good luck.

Comment: No.. i just want understand what is the purpose of S2 and S4..

Comment: So what do you think? What will happen when they are closed? (BTW, I have never seen such a description of DFF.. it's rather..interesting)

Comment: D pass through.. i think that S1 is P and S4 is P. but so, what is the purpose of S2 and S4?

Comment: They short the out of the cascaded inverters to their input. Which, as far as I understand is supposed to emulate a one bit memory.

Comment: Yeah I know. But how does it matter whether if they will be P or N? How will this affect?

Comment: It will affect the synchronization with the other switches. Once you lock the bit in the loop, you want to disconnect it's input, right?

Comment: If clk=0 i want that the value of D will pass until S3 and just if CLK=1 this value need to pass until Q. Now, hwo can i understand if the value need to pass through the NOT'S or not?

Comment: Divide it into stages. This architecture resembles the master-slave edge triggered D-FF. Perhaps you might want to look at it first.

Comment: Yes i know. the left is the Master and the right is the Slave, but I still can not figure out how to understand the meaning of the S2 and S4

Comment: Can you make the master work ignoring the slave? After you do, proceed with the slave.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: Master-slave D-FF is consisting of two D-latches. You can separate the circuit into two D-latches. Make the two parts to work like D-latches by selecting the proper polarity for the switches. Then proceed.

Comment: In fact, why it important that if clk=0 so S2 need to be open?

Comment: Because otherwise it will have two different possible solutions. It can be positive edge triggered or negative-edge triggered.

Comment: Hwo it can be negative-edge triggered? (if S1 is P and S4 is P)

Comment: if `S2` is closed on `clk=0` it will be negative-edge triggered

Comment: Can you explain why ? (while S1 is P and S4 is P)

Comment: if S1=P and S3=N, hwo can i understand what are S2 and S4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flip flop is two opposite phase latches back to back.

A latch consists (in this case) of a back to back inverter.
To write into a latch you must overcome the feedback inverter (trying to write old value) with the input inverter which is driving the initial bitnode.
One solution to this problem is to cut off the feedback inverter whenever the latch is transparent.

This is the purpose of the switches S2/S4: they prevent the second inverter in each chain from writing back to the input, while the latches are open.

This prevents contention, speeds up the latch, and reduces power consumption.  Very common in VLSI.  It also removes the need to size the input inverter stronger than the feedback inverter.

**Opposite phase** is the key word which helps you decide on what type of switch to use.

For a positive edge flip flop, the second latch must OPEN when the clock goes high.

Consider the situations:

```
CLK high: master latch closed, slave latch opened => S1=off,S2=on,S3=on,S4=off


CLK low : master latch open, slave latch closed => S1=on,S2=off,S3=off,S4=on
```

From here it easy to see that:

```
S1 = PMOS
S2 = NMOS
S3 = NMOS
S4 = PMOS
```

Although typically the switches S1/S3 would be transmission gates.  And S2/S4 would be tri-state inverters built into the feedback inverters of each latch.

**EDIT**

[image: basic dff]

Added a picture.  Green circle arrow shows feedback.  Red means switch is off.  Blue shows where the output data comes from.

So, when clock is low the data is stored in the master latch.
When clock goes high, the master latch is cut off from D.  Simultaneously the data from the master latch passes through the slave latch.  So, rising-edge FF.

Comment: So for what i need the chain of the NOT's?

Comment: That's the memory element.  When the switches S2 or S4 are closed, the back to back inverters hold their value without any input given.  Without these you would not be able to store your bit.  Consider the first node Q @ a logical 1.  This inverted makes a 0.  Now this is inverted and fed back into Q to sustain the original logical '1'.  Thus, memory is formed.

Comment: When S2 is closed (for example) ,so the value that pass through S2 is not equal to the value that pass Through the chain NOT's?

Comment: @Mathmatic: I honestly don't even understand your question.  When S2 is closed then there is no feedback from the second inverter in the master latch to the input.  So, whatever you put in D passes through S1 and shows up in the latch.  If S2 was not there, the feedback inverter and the input driver would "fight" when writing a new value.  For it to work properly, the input driver needs to be stronger than the feedback inverter.  Otherwise it will never "flip the bit".

Comment: Can you explain it: "When S2 is closed then there is no feedback from the second inverter in the master latch to the input. " ? [why it so?]

Comment: I will add a picture.

Comment: OK ty, and I do not know if it is possible to ask, but I think it will be more effective, you might have Skype? [The correspondence will be faster]

Comment: Ok, it's so clear now, ty. By the way, if If I have more questions, can I ask you?

Comment: can you help me here(?): http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251872/cycle-time-between-flip-flops-with-delay

Comment: @Mathmatic: Why would I? the first question you asked, which i answered, you said it was what you were looking for, but you never accepted the answer.

Comment: Because I did not understand the form of exercise with switches for DFF (it was the first time I saw this exercise). But at the end I understood what you said! (The problem was me. The photo you uploaded caused me to understand - Maybe it will this time too.)

Comment: @Mathmatic: If my answer sufficiently explained your confusion, then you should accept my answer?

Comment: I think you've explained it excellent and at the end I realized it.

Comment: Ok, i did it now

Comment: By the way, can you help me with the other question? [notice: i think i undertand things fastest by pictures :) ]

Comment: You know hwo to solve the other question?